# How to put a googlemap fragment inside a Tab of a (Fixed Tabs + Swipe) Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I like to put an instance of google maps inside one fragment of a FragmentActivity, I tried to do it but it but I dont find samples of how to do it, I implemented a simple map in a static activity and it runs perfectly but when I put it inside a tab of fragmented activity it throws me exceptions.
Anyone have samples of doing what I want ? i've searched but I dont find samples

Comment: You should use getChildFragmentManager() on FragmentActivity instead of getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find *the* samples: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro
Don't forget adding a API key created with a [debug certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).